# gspread requires an older google-auth

Tags: python, pip, gspread, google-auth-library

Today `pip -install --user --upgrade` told me

```
gspread 5.7.0 requires google-auth==1.12.0, but you have google-auth 2.14.1 which is incompatible.
```

Please note the huge discrepancy in `google-auth` version numbers: **1.12** vs **2.14**.

I think I update my packages often enough, so this huge jump in `google-auth` version numbers is a surprise. What has happened?

I assume that the current `gspread` won't work with `google-auth` v2, so another (more important) question is when will it be updated, if ever?

What do other `gspread` users do?

Comment: I've added a comment that it is being addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436110/python-handling-incompatible-package-dependencies-google-api-and-gspread#comment131403173_74436110). A lot of times a work-around is also offered to use in the meantime as the updating grinds away. I wasn't seeing that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [has been reported](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1125) and was claimed to be fixed by [adding dependabot to maintain dependencies](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/1126).

It was *actually* fixed in **v5.7.1**. See [Remove fixed version for google dependency system](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1145).