# Python - Handling Incompatible Package Dependencies - Google API and Gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, google-analytics-api, gspread

I have been utilizing the [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) to get universal analytics data. My request has ran fine until trying to push the final dataframe to a Gsheet utilizing Gspread.

There are what appears to be package incompatibility issues between gspread and google-auth, see below. I am on windows, utilizing a jupyter notebook, python version 3.9

When Running `pip install gspread`

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
> all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
> the following dependency conflicts. google-api-python-client 2.50.0
> requires google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=1.16.0, but you have google-auth
> 1.12.0 which is incompatible. google-api-core 2.8.1 requires google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0, but you have google-auth 1.12.0 which is
> incompatible.

When running `pip install --upgrade google-auth`

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
> all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
> the following dependency conflicts. gspread 5.7.0 requires
> google-auth==1.12.0, but you have google-auth 2.14.1 which is
> incompatible.

**What is the best way to resolve dependency conflicts (if you can)?** I'm new to this and unsure how to research if there is a particular version of google-auth that will satisfy all packages in my specific case.

Comment: The good news is that it is in the process of being addressed, see [Bump google-auth from 1.12.0 to 2.14.1](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/1142), and [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1125#issue-1426185227). Unfortunately, those issue/pull requests don't list a work-around or link to one. See also [gspread requires an older google-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74434493/8508004).

Comment: The current solution to this is actually [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1145) the fixed versions will be removed soon. Newer versions will come with next major upgrade of gspread.